# iPhone 6S, Delete HiCalculator App

Tags: ios, applications

How do you uninstall the HiCalculator app? I have tried the usual, hold down till jiggles and click on the X. Does not work, it won't jiggle. I have researched and researched on internet, cannot find an answer.

Comment: Can you hold down another app icon?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried doing it the iTunes way?

iTunes -> iPhone -> Applications -> HiCalculator -> Remove
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Storage: Manage Storage. The app should appear in this list. Find it, touch it, and then scroll down to "Delete."